# Agrupar e somar dados do retorno json com jquery

Tags: jquery

Possuo este Json que retorna do banco, preciso consolidar os dados que são iguais mas não tenho ideia de como fazer no jquery ou no php. Se alguem tiver alguma sugestão Agradeço!

```
  {  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "nome_pesquisa":"teste",
         "nr_pergunta":"1",
         "pergunta":"a",
         "qtd":"40"
      },
      {  
         "nome_pesquisa":"teste",
         "nr_pergunta":"2",
         "pergunta":"b",
         "qtd":"29"
      },
      {  
         "nome_pesquisa":"teste",
         "nr_pergunta":"2",
         "pergunta":"b",
         "qtd":"11"
      },
      {  
         "nome_pesquisa":"teste",
         "nr_pergunta":"3",
         "pergunta":"c",
         "qtd":"3"
      },
      {  
         "nome_pesquisa":"teste",
         "nr_pergunta":"3",
         "pergunta":"c",
         "qtd":"5"
      },
      {  
         "nome_pesquisa":"teste",
         "nr_pergunta":"3",
         "pergunta":"c",
         "qtd":"2"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Consolidar de que forma? Somar os valores e deixar apenas 1 dos iguais?

Comment: isso mesmo, no caso apareceria uma vez cada pergunta com o total somado dela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para reduzir o array deixando apenas uma entrada para cada pergunta, distinguindo através do `nr_pergunta`, pode utilizar a função [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Para cada elemento procura se ele existe, e caso já exista soma a quantidade. Quando não existe apenas o adiciona ao array que está a ser construido.

Implementação:

```js
let json = `
{
 "data": [{
   "nome_pesquisa": "teste",
   "nr_pergunta": "1",
   "pergunta": "a",
   "qtd": "40"
  },
  {
   "nome_pesquisa": "teste",
   "nr_pergunta": "2",
   "pergunta": "b",
   "qtd": "29"
  },
  {
   "nome_pesquisa": "teste",
   "nr_pergunta": "2",
   "pergunta": "b",
   "qtd": "11"
  },
  {
   "nome_pesquisa": "teste",
   "nr_pergunta": "3",
   "pergunta": "c",
   "qtd": "3"
  },
  {
   "nome_pesquisa": "teste",
   "nr_pergunta": "3",
   "pergunta": "c",
   "qtd": "5"
  },
  {
   "nome_pesquisa": "teste",
   "nr_pergunta": "3",
   "pergunta": "c",
   "qtd": "2"
  }
 ]
}`;

let perguntas = JSON.parse(json).data;
//tornar a quantidade numérica para a soma funcionar como esperado
perguntas.forEach(perg => perg.qtd = Number(perg.qtd)); 

let perguntasAgrupadas = perguntas.reduce(function(acc, curr){
  let encontrado = false;
  for (let pergunta of acc){
    if (pergunta.nr_pergunta == curr.nr_pergunta){
      pergunta.qtd += curr.qtd;
      encontrado = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if (!encontrado)
    acc.push(curr);
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(perguntasAgrupadas);
```

Comment: Isac Muito Obrigado! Funcionou Perfeitamente! Vou ler mais sobre esta função "reduce".

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar também `filter` após somar e apagar os itens repetidos (lembrando que o método abaixo tem compatibilidade com o IE):

```js
var json = {  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "nome_pesquisa":"teste",
         "nr_pergunta":"1",
         "pergunta":"a",
         "qtd":"40"
      },
      {  
         "nome_pesquisa":"teste",
         "nr_pergunta":"2",
         "pergunta":"b",
         "qtd":"29"
      },
      {  
         "nome_pesquisa":"teste",
         "nr_pergunta":"2",
         "pergunta":"b",
         "qtd":"11"
      },
      {  
         "nome_pesquisa":"teste",
         "nr_pergunta":"3",
         "pergunta":"c",
         "qtd":"3"
      },
      {  
         "nome_pesquisa":"teste",
         "nr_pergunta":"3",
         "pergunta":"c",
         "qtd":"5"
      },
      {  
         "nome_pesquisa":"teste",
         "nr_pergunta":"3",
         "pergunta":"c",
         "qtd":"2"
      }
   ]
}

var temp_array = [];

$.each(json.data, function(e,v){
   var items = v.nr_pergunta+v.pergunta;
   
   if(temp_array.indexOf(items) == -1){
      temp_array.push(e);
      temp_array.push(items);
   }else{
      var array_pos = temp_array[temp_array.indexOf(items)-1];
      var soma = parseInt(json.data[array_pos].qtd) + parseInt(v.qtd);
      json.data[array_pos].qtd = soma.toString();
      delete json.data[e];
   }
});

json = json.data.filter(function(n){ return n }); 

console.log(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: dvd , obrigado pelo auxilio , vou estudar as duas opções, tanto o filter como o reduce. Vlw!